# Connecting with AWS IoT Core Using WebSocket Protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, node-red, aws-iot

I'm trying to connect to AWS IoT Core using MQTT, WebSocket and HTTPS communication protocols.

Here I'm using Node-Red as an IoT Device simulator. While doing this I'm able to successfully connect using both MQTT and HTTPS protocol but WebSocket connection is not working.

***MQTT EndPoint:*** xxxx..amazonaws.com:8883

***HTTPS EndPoint:*** https://xxxx..amazonaws.com:8443/topics/iot%2Ftelemetry?qos=1

***WebSocket EndPoint:*** wss://xxxx..amazonaws.com:443/mqtt

**Error in Node-Red Console when I try to publish a message to AWS IoT Core using WebSocket protocol**

`"An error occurred while sending:  Error: WebSocket is not open: readyState 3 (CLOSED)"`

The above error clearly states that Node-Red is not able to establish the WebSocket connection due to incorrect configuration.

Can anyone who has connected to AWS IoT Core using WebSocket protocol share some pointers here?

Comment: I wonder if this might be down to not having ALPN support in the MQTT node just yet. Details [here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/2434) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/mqtt-with-tls-client-authentication-on-port-443-why-it-is-useful-and-how-it-works/)

Comment: But according to AWS IoT Core documentation, "ALPN protocol name" is "NA" for "MQTT over WebSocket" and it's only applicable for MQTT and HTTPS. Details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html)

Comment: Adding the 'ALPNProtocols'  to '["x-amzn-mqtt-ca"]' still didn't help :(